# ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer not triggered after first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I put an alert("First Load") to determine if this ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer is triggered , it works first initial page load. However, when I selected other events( edit, add, usercontrol) the alert("First Load") that I put is not showing anymore therefore ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer not triggered.  How to triggered this ?

I've Tried this first page load it triggred but not when I fire the other events ..

```
 window.onload = function() 
       {
           alert("Onload");
            //Check File API support
           if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) 
            {


                $('.ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer input').on("change", function(event) {
                    alert("First Load");
                    var files = event.target.files; //FileList objec
```

also I tried this but not solve my problem

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       // window.onload = function() 
      // {
           alert("Onload");
            //Check File API support
           if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) 
            {


                $('.ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer input').on("change", function(event) {
                    alert("First Load");
```

I expect that eventhough I select other events , my ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer  should also fire. 
[here is the html ] https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGdqP.png

Comment: can you add your HTML also?

Comment: please see it on  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGdqP.png